# Обновление БД Room при добавлении новых полей в таблицу

Tags: android, android-room

Есть БД с двумя таблицами.. В одну из таблиц "category" добавил два новых поля image и comments. Как обновить БД у существующих пользователей теперь?

Класс описывающий таблицу Category

```
@Entity(tableName = "category")
public class Category {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(typeAffinity = INTEGER)
    private int id;
    @ColumnInfo(typeAffinity = TEXT)
    private String name;

    public Category(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Нужно повысить версию базы и добавить миграцию версий, в которой обычным SQL-запросом добавить колонки. Пример с разъяснениями можно посмотреть здесь: https://startandroid.ru/ru/courses/architecture-components/27-course/architecture-components/540-urok-12-migracija-versij-bazy-dannyh.html

Comment: А как быть, если используется готовая БД уже.. Т.е. была база в assets например с таблицей products, я добавил новое поле "comments" и перезалил БД в assets. Сделал две миграции. В первой миграции из старых таблиц скопировал все данные в новые таблицы, во второй миграции добавил запросом поле comments, и скопировал в таблицу products все поля включая поле comments.. Но при выборке в поле comments null.

Comment: @Kolhoznik, не нужно спрашивать в чужих вопросах (если только мелкие пояснения) - задайте свой. Тут неизвестно как и что вы делали - скорее всего где-то в логике ошиблись и обновление не прошло как надо. Если у вас база не пополняется в процессе использования, то вы можете просто грохнуть её и скопировать новую версию из ассетов.

Comment: ок, покопаюсь еще.. если не получится задам вопрос. Спасибо)